# Node start script env not being set on Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, package.json

I have to following which seems to work on Windows (and Linux as far as I can tell):

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test || SET \"NODE_ENV=test\"&& mocha **/*.test.js --reporter spec"
}
```

But it doesn't work on OSX for some reason, I tried doing just `NODE_ENV=test` but that doesn't work either, any thoughts?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `export` before the variable name, just like you do `SET` in windows:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test || SET \"NODE_ENV=test\" && mocha **/*.test.js --reporter spec"
}
```